# Loading JSON Tags into Select2 with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

Ok, so I am using the code below to grab a list of tags and load it up into a select2 box. The options are being returned as `["test1","test2"]` which should be the correct format, but **I am assuming they need to be processed in a loop** somehow.

```
    //This part is meant to grab the options. I am using model ID 473 for testing

    $('#ticket_style_id').on("change", function(e) { 
      var tag_list = $.ajax({
        url: "/grab_options/<%= 473 %>",
        async: false
       }).responseText;

     //This part is meant to load the tag_list into a select2 box based on the 
     //selection above        

      $("#ticket_option_list").select2({
        tags: [ tag_list ]
      });
  })
```

[image]

Interestingly if I substitute the following:

```
 $("#ticket_option_list").select2({
        tags: ["test1","test2"]
      });
```

...everything generates fine.

[image]

The JSON is being returned by this controller code:

```
def grab_options
    style = Style.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render json: style.option_list.to_json }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Is your response a string or a JSON object? If it is a JSON object, you might want to add `dataType: "json"` to your ajax settings object, to make sure it is actually interpreted as JSON. Alternatively, you can set the content type of your response to `application/json`.

Comment: It should be a JSON object. See my edit

Comment: What does `tag_list` log when you use `console.log(tag_list)`?  Just an array?

Comment: By the way, I would HIGHLY discourage the `async: false` option, especially for autocomplete boxes.  It's a pain for any user on a slowish connection.

Comment: Console log = ["test1","test2"]

Comment: Steve, what would you suggest as an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the following approach for 2 reasons:

1) It forces the response to be interpreted as JSON (because of `dataType: 'json'`)

2) It uses the success callback instead of using `async: false`

```
$('#ticket_style_id').on("change", function(e) { 
  var tag_list = $.ajax({
    url: "/grab_options/<%= 473 %>",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      $("#ticket_option_list").select2({
        tags: response
      });    
    }
  });
});
```

EDIT:

That being said, I believe `Select2` has a built in AJAX method that you can see in their [tutorial](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).

Comment: I just updated my code to handle the correct response content.