# select2 4.0 AJAX pre-fill howto?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jquery-select2

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30499636/populate-select2-with-json-after-init-doesnt-work), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25451010/nested-select2-with-dependent-ajax-call), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835823/loading-json-tags-into-select2-with-ajax) and according to the documentation [the most important here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316586/select2-4-0-0-initial-value-with-ajax#30328989), but none of them work for me.
I'm trying to use AJAX select2. I'm trying to make a generic "select" item.

So for all the elements that have a `data-select2-json` attribute, i apply a `select2` with the ajax URL that is in the `data-select2-json` value.

```
$('[data-select2-json!=""][data-select2-json]').each(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('data-select2-json');
    var pg_size = $(this).attr('data-select2-page-size') | 30;
    $(this).select2({
        language: language_code,
        tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
        ajax: {
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 300,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term, // -> q=[search term]
                    page: params.page // -> page=[no page]
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                params.page = params.page || 1;
                console.log(data.items);
                return {
                    results: data.items,
                    pagination: {
                      more: (params.page * pg_size) < data.total
                    }
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        // let our custom formatter work
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        templateResult: formatRepo,
        templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
    });
});
```

It works well!

[image: works well]

JSON the server sends is always formatted like this:

```
{"items":
    [{"item": "Fran\u00e7ais", "id": 1},
     {"item": "Finlandais", "id": 5},
     {"item": "Chinois simplifi\u00e9", "id": 15}
    ],
"total": 3}
```

It's very close to the AJAX sample you [can find in the documentation](https://select2.github.io/examples.html). My problem is AJAX initiatilize: I want either to add the values in the HTML:

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control"
        data-select2-json="/fr/chez-moi/tags/langues"
        multiple="multiple"
        name="known_languages">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Français</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Chinois simplifié</option>
</select>
```

and then initialize with select2 (= the code `$(this).select2({..` above ) but this doesnt work and gives me blank values:

[image: blank value]

NB: [the solution here given by Kevin Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316586/select2-4-0-0-initial-value-with-ajax#30328989) doesn't work either and gives me exactly the same result.

The other solution is to ask in AJAX to the URL with a parameter like "`&init=1`" (or something like that) so the server will send results with added parameters like `checked: true` for each value, and I will call `select2` with those values.

Nothing clear in the documentation on how to pre-fill `select2`. How should I do?

Here are my other functions:

```
function item_or_text(obj) {
    if (typeof(obj.item)!='undefined') {
        return (obj.item.length ? obj.item : obj.text);
    }
    return obj.text;
}

function formatRepo(data) {
    if (data.loading) return data.text;
    var markup = item_or_text(data);
    console.log('formatRepo', data, markup);
    return markup;
}

function formatRepoSelection(item) {
    var retour = item_or_text(item);
    console.log('formatRepoSelection', item, item.item, retour);
    return retour;
}
```

Comment: Did my answer not work for you? Please provide feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a [working example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z8o9u3d4/1/) using the example code provided on the [Select2 Examples](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) page. I just had to change their example select tag to accept multiple like yours:

```
<select multiple="multiple" ...
```

I also added a second default selected option:

```
<option value="3620194" selected="selected">select2/select2</option>
<option value="317757" selected="selected">Modernizr/Modernizr</option>
```

If you have a look at the fiddle, you will see it working how you would like yours to work.

You did not include the code for your `templateSelection: formatRepoSelection` method. My guess is that method is the cause of your problem. The code used on the examples page is:

```
function formatRepoSelection(repo) {
  return repo.full_name || repo.text;
}
```

Although I have no idea what your `formatRepoSelection` code is, I think if you change it to something like the following, your issue will be solved:

```
function formatRepoSelection(repo) {
  return repo.item;
}
```

Comment: I check you answer as valid because your answer works for sure. I woke up 4 hours later, tried my code and everything was working: I really dont know why. Didnt touch a thing! I'm addind options + selected options like you suggest. Maybe working 14hours a day for 10days is a bit too much... Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this as follows:
Just before execute select2() on select element, get it's initial value:

```
var initval = selector.attr("value");
```

After converting it to select2 create an option with initval:

```
if (initval) {
    var option = new Option(initval, initval, true, true);
    selector.append(option).trigger('change');
}
```

You can do something similar for multivalue select element.