# Select2 4.0 - when edit multiple shows id but not title

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-select2

I have problem. I've made ajax json multiple tags with select2 it works great, but problem stars when i try to edit and insert selected early values like this:

```
<select id="select2" name="field">
    <option value="1" selected>title 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>title 2</option>
</select>
```

It seems like Select2 doesn't recognized that value must be value, and title should show as tag.

[image]

My js code that i use for get json:

[image]

I was trying to give data: json_data but without results. How to reload Select2 to show title but not id ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select2 4.0 AJAX pre-fill howto?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34405690/select2-4-0-ajax-pre-fill-howto)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution here: 
[select2 4.0 AJAX pre-fill howto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34405690/select2-4-0-ajax-pre-fill-howto?rq=1)

thanks to related questions - i didn't know how to give a question and author of it:

Fraser Crosbie